# MediaSource API appendBuffer() appendArrayBuffer() append() which one to use in Chrome?

Tags: html, video

i read the spec of MediaSource API :
http://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/ (working draft)
and
https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/media-source/media-source.html (editor draft)

the first reference SourceBuffer method : appendArrayBuffer()
the second : appendBuffer()

in chrome it seems that the only method available on SourceBuffer is append() but i dont find any documentation on that one.

Can someone let me know if he have more infos on the append() method in chrome and if any browser implement the appendBuffer() or appendArrayBuffer() ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current versions of Chrome (ie 25-stable, 26-beta, & 27-dev) essentially support the [October 8th version](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/6d127e69c9f8/media-source/media-source.html) of the Media Source Extensions spec. We are in the process of updating the implementation to reflect the current editors draft. There have been a lot of changes in the spec and it is going to take some time to get it all working.

For now you should just use the older version of the spec to implement your application.

Comment: Hi Aaron. I've been able to use the Media Source API with a split WebM file. Is it possible, somehow, to do the same with a MP4/H264. Do I need to create the chunks in some special way?

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the exact implemented version of specs. Is there an easy way to match chrome version with spec version ?

Comment: @WooDzu, Yes MP4 is supported, but you have to make sure they are fragmented MP4 files. You can use MP4Box like [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11583712/1352283) suggests to make sure the files are in the proper format.

Comment: @FlintMakal there is no easy way to map spec version to Chrome Version. At least for the versions I have mentioned you can count on October 8th spec behavior. Once appendBuffer() becomes available in a later version you can count on at least 1 full Chrome version before the old append() method is removed.

Answer (score 0):

After searching the specs revisions history it seems that chrome don't implement current spec which was changed on :

```
Version Comment
04 January 2013 
Renamed append() to appendArrayBuffer() and made appending asynchronous.
Added SourceBuffer.appendStream().
Added SourceBuffer.setTrackInfo() methods.
Added issue boxes to relevant sections for outstanding bugs.
```

so append() was the old method name