# Can I create a growing file source URL which is not a video/audio Type?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, streaming, media-source

I have read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546994/steaming-a-growing-file-using-the-mediasource-api), but this is a video's solution.
Now, I want create a non vidoe/audio sourceBuffer url. I don't know how to implement it. I think that maybe mediasource is not support.

```
<script>
    var ms = new MediaSource();
    var src = window.URL.createObjectURL(ms);
    console.log(src);

    // sourceopen is not work.
    // I don't know if i can create a non audio/video type growing file url?
    ms.addEventListener('sourceopen', function(e) {
        var sourceBuffer = ms.addSourceBuffer('application/octet-stream');
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/test.bin', true);  // just a binary content
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status >= 400) {
                alert('Unexpected status code ' + xhr.status);
                return false;
            }
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(xhr.response);
        };
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: You can define a new media type [14.1 Defining a new media type (beyond the existing Audio and Video types)](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#defining-a-new-media-type-beyond-the-existing-audio-and-video-types).  What data are you trying to stream?

Comment: I just send a file to client. such as download zip file.

Comment: _"I just send a file to client, but sometime I want it to be sent only 0-300 bytes."_ What is issue? Do you send file to client as `ArrayBuffer` or  `Blob`?

Comment: Not certain what requirement is?

Comment: My case is that the server side is recieving data, and send data to client at the same time.

Comment: Can you include `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: `application/octet-stream` does not appear to be not a supported type at `MediaSource`;  try `MediaSource.isTypeSupported("application/octet-stream")`. Where is output of streamed data expected to be reviewed or displayed? Is file data a string? What is purpose of using `MediaSource`?

Comment: Are you trying to output a text stream to a `<video>` element?

Comment: No, I just want to send file from server to client but the size of this file is growing up, maybe another process is writing it at the same time.

Comment: You can use `Blob`, `FileReader` to reassemble, append bytes into single file at client, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899536/method-for-streaming-data-from-browser-to-server-via-http