# Encoding FFMPEG to MPEG-DASH – or WebM with Keyframe Clusters – for MediaSource API

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, h.264, webm

I'm currently sending a video stream to Chrome, to play via the MediaSource API.

As I understand it, MediaSource only supports MP4 files encoded with MPEG-DASH, or WebM files that have clusters beginning with keyframes (otherwise it raises the error: Media segment did not begin with keyframe).

Is there any way to encode in MPEG-DASH or keyframed WebM formats with FFMPEG in real-time?

**Edit:**

I just tried it with `ffmpeg ... -f webm -vcodec vp8 -g 1` so that every frame is a keyframe. Not the ideal solution. It does work with MediaStream now though. Any way to sync up the segments with the keyframes in WebM so not every frame needs to be a keyframe?

---

**Reference Questions on WebM / MP4 and MediaSource:**

[Media Source Api not working for a custom webm file (Chrome Version 23.0.1271.97 m)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037112/media-source-api-not-working-for-a-custom-webm-file-chrome-version-23-0-1271-97/14048349#14048349)

[MediaSource API and mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316859/mediasource-api-and-mp4/10287861#11583712)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To ensure every cluster in your WebM starts with a keyframe, try something like this:

```
ffmpeg \
  [...inputs] \
  -vcodec libvpx \
  -keyint_min 60 \
  -g 60 \
  -vb 4000k \
  -f webm \
  -cluster_size_limit 10M \
  -cluster_time_limit 2100 \
  [...output]
```

Basically, as implemented, every keyframe has to be at the beginning of a cluster but the inverse is not true.  That is, on key frame there will be a new cluster, but on new cluster there won't necessarily be a keyframe.  To get around this issue, we simply set the cluster size to something large that we'll never hit.

In this example, we'll have a keyframe every 2 seconds, and the cluster time limit is 2.1 seconds, so we'll never hit it.  The bitrate is 4Mbit, and the cluster size limit is 10M-something.  Not sure if it's bit or byte there but it doesn't matter as we'll never hit it as I've set it much greater than it needs to be.

Comment: This is fantastically helpful and should be the accepted answer now.

Comment: I agree! Also, Brad knows way too much about this stuff :)

Comment: am keep getting this error: ``Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: pipe:0: End of file``

Answer (score 11):

At the moment FFMPEG does not support DASH encoding. You can segment with FFMPEG (https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment), but I recommend combining FFMPEG and MP4Box. Use FFMPEG to transcode your live video, and then MP4Box to segment and create the .mpd index.

MP4Box is a part of GPAC (http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/).

Here is an example using h264:

```
ffmpeg -threads 4 -f v4l2 -i  /dev/video0 -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -r 30 -s 1280x720  -f mp4 -y "$movie" > temp1.mp4 && MP4Box -dash 10000 -frag 1000 -rap "$movie"
```

If you need VP8 (WebM), use: `-vcodec libvpx` and `-f webm` or `-f ts`.

Comment: Thanks Cibráne. Is MP4Box able to encode a real-time pipe? We're going for a low-latency live stream. Any further advice would be hugely appreciated! Or is there a way to stream WebM directly from FFMPEG with keyframes at every cluster?

Comment: Yes, you can use MP4Box to segment Live Video. The idea is here: http://www.slideshare.net/cconcolato/live-streaming-of-video-and-subtitles-with-mpegdash  For the sgementer is the same job segment VP8 or H264.

Comment: Is this still up-to-date?  It looks like there is at least some limited DASH support now.  https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#webm_005fdash_005fmanifest

Answer (score 10):

Another user has had some luck with:

```
ffmpeg ... \
  -f mp4 \
  -reset_timestamps 1 \
  -movflags empty_moov+default_base_moof+frag_keyframe \
  -probesize 200000
```

Please see see galbarm's questions at:

- [Live streaming dash content using mp4box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617673/live-streaming-dash-content-using-mp4box)
- [Flush & Latency Issue with Fragmented MP4 Creation in FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868854/flush-latency-issue-with-)

Note: If you don't have keyframes on the input video, you may need to set:

```
-frag_duration 100000
```

... instead of `+frag_keyframe`.

Comment: I think this (original) answer might still be genuinely useful to some folks who are doing ultra-low latency real-time steaming, so I'm going to leave this here for now. If you think this answer is a no-op, let me know and I'll delete it. (Or, if you have a better solution for zero-latency streaming, please post it!)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same situation when trying to play recorded .webm file by **MediaRecorder API** back using **Media Source Extensions** (MSE). Chrome (51) recordings are malformed, Firefox (46) seems OK.

To get it working you have to fix cues in .webm file:

1. clone https://github.com/webmproject/libwebm
2. make sure you have cmake version >= 3.2 (https://askubuntu.com/questions/610291/how-to-install-cmake-3-2-on-ubuntu-14-04)
3. `cmake .`
4. `make`
5. `./sample_muxer -i original.webm -o fixed.webm`
6. load fixed.webm into DASH / your own player!

Hope it helped someone. It was quite difficult to google any information without the DASH keyword (i am not using DASH, only the same underlying technology - MSE) :)

Comment: You can also compile libwebm under Windows using Visual Studio. It has worked like a charm.